# Immutable.js performance with complicated objects

Tags: redux, realm, react-redux, immutable.js

i'm using Immutable.js along with redux architecture in mobile app.
Now i need to use [realm](https://realm.io) database here. Let's say i've queried 5 objects from Realm. It outputs not a plain objects, but "Realm objects", which are basically some kind of references to db.

So, the problem is: it takes ~130ms to query data from database and 5 seconds (!!!) to put it into Immutable state.

Is there way to somehow prevent immutable.js from processing only this specific array of objects (search results) without hacks and pass it as usual into store?

Answer (score 0):

Realm should not take this long to access objects. Make sure you aren't in chrome debug mode when doing your benchmarking